# Function returning $\left\lvert x \right\rvert$, $0$ or $-\left\lvert x \right\rvert$, depending on input

Tags: absolute-value

## Function returning $\left\lvert x \right\rvert$, $0$ or $-\left\lvert x \right\rvert$, depending on input

I have a function $m(x, y)$ that returns
$\left\lvert x \right\rvert$ if $y$ is positive ($y > 0$),
$0$ if $y$ is $0$ ($y = 0$),
or $-\left\lvert x \right\rvert$ if $y$ is negative ($y < 0$). One important rule is that **there mustn't be *any* 'if's (case destinctions) in the function**.
This function was originally intended to behave like an activation function in a neural network, but now it's stuck in my mind. I can't find any solution.
*If the question turns out to be impossible without an **if**, is it possible where $m(x, y)$ with negative y returns $1$ instead?*
So far I have: $$m(x, y) = \left\lvert x \right\rvert \times f(y)\\f(y) = $$ in which $f(y)$ follows:
$f(y) = 1$ where $y > 0$,
$f(y) = 0$ where $y = 0$,
$f(y) = -1$ where $y < 0$.

#### Compact version of question:

Convert the following function into one without case destinction.
$$m(x, y) = 
        \begin{Bmatrix}
        \left\lvert x \right\rvert : y > 0 \\
        0 : y = 0 \\
        -\left\lvert x \right\rvert : y < 0 \\
        \end{Bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Does anyone know more tags I should add?

Comment: How about just $m(x,y)=|x|\cdot \text{sgn}(y)$, where $\text{sgn}$ denotes the [*sign function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) (a function that is $-1$ for negative, $1$ for positive values and $0$ at $0$)

Comment: The $sgn$ function uses set-builder notation.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'll post an answer using the $\text{sgn}$ function.

Comment: Btw, this notation is not set builder notation (as you do not use it to build a set). -- But as you complain that signum requires case distinction, how come you are okay with $|x|$? Doesn't it use case distinction as well? Or if you define it as $|x|:=\max\{x,-x\}$, doesn't $\max$ use case distinction?

Comment: Also, since $m(1,y)=\operatorname{sgn}(y)$, your problem is *equivalent* to finding an acceptable notation for the signum function

Comment: I suspect he's trying to program something in a language that does support a native absolute function but not a sign function

Comment: No, but it's more like a puzzle that I couldn't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$\text{sgn}(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{|x|+1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{-x}{|-x|+1}\right\rfloor$$

then $\text{sgn}(x)$ takes on $-1$ when $x<0$, $1$ whenever $x>0$ and $0$ when $x=0$.

Now the function you're looking for is

$$m(x,y)=|x|\cdot \text{sgn}(y)$$

Comment: Or, if the floor function gets disqualifeid by the OP, let $\operatorname{sgn}(x):=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{x}{|x|+h}$ :)

Comment: Alternatively, we can do $\text{sgn}(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty} \tanh(nx)$ :)

Comment: Isn't $|-x|$ the same as $|x|$?

Comment: It is, but it makes it clearer why the expression works